# Get Character Representation of a Unicode value In Java

Tags: java, xml, unicode, unicode-escapes

I want the character representation of a Unicode value in Java.
Can this be done ?

Some characters (example is the character whose unicode value is \u001b) are not supported in XML. So I am escaping them in the XML by putting the Unicode value '\u001b' and after unmarshalling, I want the character representation of \u001b to displayed.
Can this be done in Java ?

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Integer.toString(character, 16)

Comment: The unicode value '\u001b' is a string.
And the character in the above argument takes in a int object.
How do we do that ?

Comment: ups this is the other way around ... this value cannot be displayed it's an escape char http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1b/index.htm

Comment: so, no way that in run time I can get the character representation of a character using its Unicode value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    String s = "\\u0031";
    char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2), 16);
    System.out.print(c);
```

output

```
1
```

though I would suggest to use XML numeric character references http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference like `&#x001b;` then it would be decoded by XML parser automatically

Answer (score -1):

```
 String fileName = "outputFile.txt";
 String str = "String with unicode" ;

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
    out.write(str);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

This should do

Comment: Hi Nigul,
Where does this file get generated ?

Comment: in project root directory. U can of course pass File object to FileOutputStream with any absolute path u wish it to be generated in ;)

Comment: Could not find it in the root folder :(
Tried giving an absolute path in the variable fileName too. Did not work.
Does it work for you ?

Comment: try not a fileName as string, but as java.io.File

Comment: yes, it does. Maybe make a search on your machine. This is a standard java File generation